Wind Implementation in UAV Package Delivery
I am currently looking to implement a Continuous Von Karman Wind Turbulence Model onto the MATLAB UAV Package Delivery Example Model of the UAV Toolbox app.
Currently I've tried adding on the Wind Turbulence model node directly onto the Environment module of the UAV model however I get an error:
"The bus data type 'EnvironmentBus' specified in 'MultirotorModel/Inner Loop and Plant Model/High-FidelityModel/Environment/Bus Creator' is not valid; the number of signals at the input to the block must match the number of object elements."
I'm not too sure how to change the model in order for it to allow more signals into the input of the block.
Screenshot of Current Simulink Model within the Environment Block:

I tried to add the Wind Turbulence model directly onto the Environment bus however it doesn't seem to accept it because of an imbalance in input signals.
How would I go about changing the model to add in a wind turbulence model
